# Writing data to JSON file in the correct category (C# Newtonsoft JSON)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to make a game within my Discord Bot where it is wholly based on Dokkan Battle, the user creates their own passive and the command can view some stats based on what they inputted.

What I'm trying to do is take this data and store it in a JSON file but the way I have it laid out I want it to write it all in one category like this so then it'll be easier to search for specific passives to display

```
{
  "userPassiveStorage": "Storage for user created passives using /passivecreator",
  "members": [
      {
          "passiveName": "",
          "leaderName": "",
          "unitHP":,
          "unitATK":,
          "unitDEF":,
          "leaderValue":,
          "passiveATK":,
          "passiveDEF":,
          "supportBuff":,
          "links": "",
      }
  ]
}
```

The way I have it done its not writing to the JSON file in the correct format, but instead stores it all as one line

```
        public void StoreUserPassives(DokkanUserPassiveBuilder classObj) 
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("UserPassivesStorage.json")) 
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                List<DokkanUserPassiveBuilder> data = new List<DokkanUserPassiveBuilder>();
                data.Add(classObj);

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray(), Formatting.Indented);
                serializer.Serialize(sw, json);
            }
        }
```

So I just need to know how can I add write another member to this category with the same properties as I showed in that JSON file
If there is an easier way rather than using categories I would like to know if that is an easier way since I just need a way to store each passive information and it needs to be easy to search

Answer (score 1):

you are serializing twice.  Try this code

```
    var path = @"UserPassivesStorage.json";
    var json = File.ReadAllText(path);

    var jsonObj =  JObject.Parse(json);

    var members =  jsonObj["members"].ToObject<List<DokkanUserPassiveBuilder>>();
    
    members.Add(classObj);
    
    jsonObj["members"] = JArray.FromObject(members);
    
    File.WriteAllText(path, jsonObj.ToString());
```

Comment: this is not writing correctly, its not writing it under the members and is instead making a json file with unknown key:value

Comment: It writes it like this where there is no category and no members


`[
  {
    "PassiveName": "Test",
    "UnitHP": 1000,
    "UnitATK": 1000,
    "UnitDEF": 1000,
    "UnitLeaderName": "Test",
    "UnitLeaderSkill": 200,
    "UnitPassiveATK": 300,
    "UnitPassiveDEF": 150,
    "Support": 30,
    "Links": "No Links Provided by the user"
  }
]`

Comment: @SamJ Your question is not clear.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok so i tried your updated answer and it is 1 step closer to it being functional but what it is doing now is just creating a new category every time when all i want is to write my data from classObj into the members only, so i have a category called UserPassiveStorage with many members with the same properties

Comment: Yep thank you, your updated answer works and its correctly adding it under members. Thank you ever so much

Comment: Yep thank you, your updated answer works and its correctly adding it under members. Thank you ever so much